# How to connect an Android application to a web based database

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, soap, ksoap

I'm fairly new to android and web based databases. I have written an android based application using the Jquery mobile framework and also phone gap.

I am looking for a way to populate my application with information held in a web based database via a request from the application.

I am not sure how to do this on the fly when the application needs the information. I have researched a little about YQL but am not sure if this will suffice.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the folloing:

1. use  ksoap2 librery as refreance in your android project
2. Develop a Webservice that has all methods and functions that you
   need in order to be   performed on External database in the cloud by
   your android project.
3. then define a way that you want to communecate with this webservice using librery added in step 1, like fom example putting your code in Aynctask or runnable or any other desgin that fit your requirements.

here is a punsh of tutorile that you can start with to get clue about how to use the Ksoap2

- [Tut1](http://javatutorialspoint.blogspot.com/2012/02/android-web-service-access-using-ksoap2.html)
- [Tut2](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data)
- [Tut3](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-web-service-access-tutorial.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I followed through the tutorial and found that this will not work for me as i am using phonegap for my application and so will not be writing and native android code.